# php/jQuery changing whether show/hide based on radio button setting from database

Tags: php, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm still new at jQuery and struggling. Finally, I can get jQuery to toggle show/hide when the button is clicked. What I'm still struggling with now is how to get show/hide to match up with the state of the button on page load. The value is coming from the database using php. So I don't know what it will be. I'd really appreciate some help!

Basically, if the button with id of 'specify' is checked, the text in the div shows; if the 'open' button is checked, the text is hidden. I set up the css so the specify class for the div makes it hidden. Should I have done that?

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="volneed" id="open" class="required" value="open to all"
 <? if($thisvolneed=='open'){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />
<label for="open"> Open to all </label>

<input type="radio" name="volneed" id="specify"  class="required" value="specify"
<? if($thisvolneed=='specify'){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> /> 
<label for="specify"> Specify types of volunteers needed </label>

<div class="specify"><p>Some info...</p></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.specify{display:none;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $("#specify").change(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(".specify").show();
    });

    $("#open").change(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(".specify").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating a class to hide the `<div>` is a fairly standard way to approach the problem.  Well done!  Instead of using the `show` or `hide` function on the `<div>`, it is just as easy to use `addClass` or `removeClass` when using the CSS approach.  Also, the initial state of the `<div>` can be shown by using PHP to apply the class if necessary on page load.

```
<div <? if($thisvolneed=='specify'){echo 'class="specify"';} ?>><p>Some info...</p></div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Just exactly what I needed to hear! I was all caught up in jQuery and not thinking about what I could do with php. Thanks Michael!

Comment: I created a show class and a hide class in CSS and used php to set the appropriate one, based on the value, just as you suggested. Worked great!

Comment: FYI the following snippet will perform the same goal using jQuery...  `if ($('#specify').attr('checked')) $('.specify').addClass('specify');`...but it is preferable to apply the class with PHP because we can.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that it's better to use php when building the page and then jQuery client side. :)

Answer (score 1):

a small try:

```
<style>
.specify{display:none;}
</style>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="volneed" id="open" class="required myOption" value="open to all" checked="checked" />
<label for="open"> Open to all </label>

<input type="radio" name="volneed" id="specify"  class="required myOption" value="specify" /> 
<label for="specify"> Specify types of volunteers needed </label>

<div class="specify"><p>Some info...</p></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myOption').click(function(){
            var $stat = $('#specify')[0].checked;
            if( $stat == true )
                $('.specify').show();
            else
                $('.specify').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

m sure it can be again optimized too..

Comment: Great! This answers a question I was about to ask about a different show/hide on my site. It uses check boxes to hide and show and I couldn't get them to hide when re-clicked. Thank you!